# Changing a CSS style within revealjs

Tags: css

I want to use revealjs with this certain style: https://revealjs-themes.dzello.com/robot-lung.html

However, I want the `.line` color to change on every slide (so within each `<section>`), which is natively not an option in the revealjs documentation. So on slide #1 I want the outline to be pink, slide #2 yellow, etc.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I looked at the documentation and Slide States (https://revealjs.com/markup/#slide-states) but didn't get that to work with the `.line` element in this specific theme.

Comment: you have to provide some codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy you may use is to handle the `slidechanged` event so that each time a new slide gets shown, all the elements having the `.line` class have their `outline-color` property changed according to a static map where each slide index is coupled to a specific color.

*EDIT: I added in the event handler the action of changing the outline color of a `.line` element not belonging to the current slide but to the whole document (but I'm not perfectly sure that's what you were asking for)

This is an example:

```css
h2{
  font-size: 80px !important;
}

.line-internal{
  outline: solid 2px pink; /*1st slide has outline color pink set via css*/
  font-size: 50px !important;
}

.line{
  outline: solid 2px pink; /*1st slide has outline color pink set via css*/
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Presentation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.6.0/css/reveal.min.css" integrity="sha512-V5fKCVKOFy36w8zJmLzPH5R6zU6KvuHOvxfMRczx2ZeqTjKRGSBO9yiZjCKEJS3n6EmENwrH/xvSwXqxje+VVA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="line">THIS IS A LINE OUTSIDE OF THE SLIDES</div>
    
    <div class="reveal">
        <div class="slides">          
            <section>
                <h2>Slide #1</h2>
                <p class="line-internal">This is the line changing outline color!</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h2>Slide #2</h2>
                <p class="line-internal">This is the line changing outline color!</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h2>Slide #3</h2>
                <p class="line-internal">This is the line changing outline color!</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h2>Slide #4</h2>
                <p class="line-internal">This is the line changing outline color!</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h2>Slide #5</h2>
                <p class="line-internal">This is the line changing outline color!</p>
            </section>            
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.6.0/js/reveal.min.js" integrity="sha512-QYXU3Cojl94ZRiZRjUZpyg1odj9mKTON9MsTMzGNx/L3JqvMA3BQNraZwsZ83UeisO+QMVfFa83SyuYYJzR9hw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script>
        
        Reveal.initialize({        
        });
        
        Reveal.addEventListener('slidechanged', function(event) {                    

          //retrieves all the .line elements from the current slide
          const lines = event.currentSlide.querySelectorAll('.line-internal');                    
          
          //color map where each slide index is coupled to a given color
          const colormap = [
            /*slide1*/  'pink',
            /*slide2*/  'yellow',
            /*slide3*/  'green',
            /*slide4*/  'blue'
          ]
          
          //select the current color based on the slide index
          //(rotating among all the available colors)
          const currentColor = colormap[event.indexh % colormap.length];                              
          
          //set the css prop outline-color of each .line-internal with the current color
          lines.forEach(line => line.style.outlineColor = currentColor);          
          
          //set the css prop outline-color of each .line with the current color
          document.querySelectorAll('.line')
            .forEach(line => line.style.outlineColor = currentColor);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense, but in my case, the `.line` elements are outside of the `slides` div.

Comment: I see the suggestion in comments to provide some code was actually appropriate. By the way everything is perfectly clear in the answer. I can't make any further guess on how it's supposed to be your scenario .. because at this point I imagine the slide to be embedded in some kind of container and the `.line` elements to belong to such frame.  If you are not just looking for a copy&paste solution it won't be hard for you to just change one single line and perform a `querySelector` over `document` instead of `event.currentSlide`. If you instead need the exact code you should share your html

Comment: Lifesaver, I was struggling with that querySelector. Thanks a billion!

Comment: you are welcome.. in the meantime I did a guess and added the feature of changing the style of a `.line` element not strictly belonging to the slide itself but to the whole document